# Closing android webview when specific url load?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have basic android webview.it is a signup page.i want to close this webview after signup and start new intent.im new to this please help.this is my code.

```
public class signupweb extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signupweb);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://aaa.freeasphost.net/signup.aspx");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (url.equals("http://aaa.freeasphost.net/MainPanel.aspx")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            } else {

                return true;
            }
        }
//    }
```

I tried this but not working.it stuck in the signup page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `context` to start new activity. Try this:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private Context context;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if (url.equals("http://aaa.freeasphost.net/MainPanel.aspx")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        } else {

            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it showing Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); i think error with this.it says MyWebViewClient(Context) cannot be applied

Comment: `webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));` use this